# Using 'BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon' of clang-format

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-format

I tried to reformat some C++ code using clang-format (version 6.0.0). Most things seem to work fine. But I fail at constructor initialize lists.

This is what I have:

```
A::A(const char* message) : B(message)
{
}
```

This is what I want:

```
A::A(const char* message) : 
   B(message)
{
}
```

I tried a clang-format file with two options:

```
ColumnLimit: '160'
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
```

And this is what I get:

```
A::A(const char *message) : B(message) {}
```

But I would like to have a line break after the colon.

It turned out that removing the `ColumnLimit` option (or setting it to `0`) fixes the issue and I get the formatting I want. But I intend to limit the line lengths so I need `ColumnLimit`.

Where is my mistake? Should the `ColumnLimit` option influence the `BreakConstructorInitializers` behavior in such a dramatic way? Or is this a bug?

**Update:** Just tried version 7.0.1. Same result.

Comment: As far as I know, the `ColumnLimit` influences lots of things, one of them being the initializer list. If clang-format can put it one line, then it does. See also `ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: `ColumnLimit` kind of overrides `BreakConstructorInitializers` even if the limit is not reached. Do you have any idea if that is desired? I also checked `ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine`, it doesn't have an influence here.

Comment: It doesn't have an influence because the line is not long enough. But yes, I find that annoying as well. But with ColumnLimit = 0, then it keeps the style that you have (but adding potential indent).

Comment: Anyway I will not use clang-format. It simply doesn't do its job. Basic indention doesn't work correctly, initializer list wrapping fails, template declaration wrapping doesn't work, removal of useless empty lines isn't done, in general it seems to fix many errors only in one way... I stopped evaluating it.

Comment: Note that `BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma` will put the initializer for `B` on a second line, unlike other settings for `BreakConstructorIntiailizers`. This seems inconsistent, and I don't really like the `BeforeComma` format, but it's something to consider.